# Need help making a CSS radial-gradient that flows seamlessly through 2 elements that are not of the same height or width

Tags: css, element, radial-gradients

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/F8v2c/3/

I'm trying to make a radial gradient that flows seamlessly between 2 sibling elements - starting from 10px or 20px to the right of the button, flowing down about half way down through the ".content" div.

I believe this just takes correctly positioning the gradients for both elements so it looks like it's one flowing radial gradient, that's the problem, I've been trying to do this but I've become frustrated - and the answer might help others.

There's a background behind the menu, so I cannot simple 'white-out' the portion next to "features" in the image below - see the jsfiddle.

See image for example.

[image: Example of radial gradient flowing through 2 elements seamlessly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted a quick update to your jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/F8v2c/9/

---

To work out the position you need to set a height on the button, then you know how much to offset the gradient by. On the button we have:

```
padding:10px;
height:21px;
```

So we know the total height of the box is 41px
*(21px height +10px top padding +10px bottom padding)*

So to have the centre of the gradient 10px below the button we would use 51px for the vertical position, the horizontal doesn't matter as long as it is the same on both the button and the dropdown. Unless the button and dropdown are the same size percentages will not work, so we will set the size of the circle in pixels (300px).

```
background-image: radial-gradient( 74px 51px, circle closest-side, rgba(171, 171, 171, 1), #0000ff 300px);
```

On the drop-down the css is almost the same except instead of the centre of the gradient being 10px below the bottom it is 10px from the top.

```
background-image: radial-gradient( 74px 10px, circle closest-side, rgba(171, 171, 171, 1), #0000ff 300px);
```

Comment: That's absolutely beautiful. I don't understand: how this syntax works when that's not the syntax that the MDN gives: http://goo.gl/c82xM and I don't think that's the syntax webkit gives either.. Or, do i just not know how to read their syntax? I've been searching for a way to make the circle a pixel amount, like you just demonstrated was possible, but i couldn't find anything on how to do it. In fact, I posted another question here on SO asking if it was possible to use a Pixel measurement and the only answer said no: http://goo.gl/dmCos I still haven't marked a correct answer.

Comment: Oh, and in your Jsfiddle, the button is messed up and is colored solid blue in Chrome, and solid white in Safari - both webkit. When i added `background-size:93px`, it fixed it. If it's set to 92px or below though, it's just a solid color. Maybe I'm missing something but I thought that was awfully strange. http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/F8v2c/12/

Comment: Thank you, glad it helped. I looked it up at http://www.webkit.org/blog/1424/css3-gradients/ it says the origin can be set in any values that background position accepts, even different units for horizontal and vertical. Not sure if that is just a webkit thing, I'll have a read of the MDN page. It does seem silly to only let you use percentages.

Comment: And I forgot to mention that it works beautifully in safari, chrome, and Firefox.